# storing multiple data in one mysql column and retrieval of data individually

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table used to score marks of an individual student:

```
studentID int(11)
studentname varchar(70)
maths_score int(11)
science_score int(11)
english_score int(11)
```

This table is in-efficient compared to the atomicity rule of maintaining databases. Is it possible to store marks of maths-science-english in one column, and can be retrieved individually? If its not possible, how do I conform to the atomicity rule?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to have them all in the same column?

Comment: to avoid making two extra columns

Comment: Don't try to out-think the model. Columns are the most efficient mechanism for this kind of data storage. Combining them to some sort of `varchar` blob monstrosity violates nearly every normalisation rule in the book, not to mention the fact that it is inefficient in terms of storage, comparison and searching.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce storage space, you might want to consider `SMALLINT` (range -32768 to 32767) or perhaps `TINYINT` (range -127 to 127), depending on your scoring. Unless, of course, your students are scoring 2147483647 on their tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But your table will not even be in First Normal Form.

To conform to the atomicity rule in this cas, you need to separate your table in three different tables. One to store student data, another one to store courses (English, Science) and other to store test scores for each student/course combination.

Answer (score 2):

You should **always** normalise such data into separate columns. Placing a selection different data into one combined column is a violation of first normal form, which is a standard (if not a requirement) for relational database models.

However, you may duplicate the data into an additional column that allows you to perform certain queries more efficiently. Duplication is a lesser evil than denormalisation. For example, you could store a `total_score` column that saves you recomputing some form of weighted average, but it would be a bad idea to collapse scores down into one column.

If you're looking for a way to store an arbitrary number of scores, create a table for "subjects" and a table for "scores", and link them so that each student can have multiple scores, each of which relates to a subject.

Answer (score 0):

Never encode columns into one in a database, you'd lose the ability to search easily. You can use tinyint if you're concerned about the space used.

Comment: True, though losing the ability to search is a minor issue compared to the fundamental violation of first normal form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store many attributes in one column and then retrieve them individually.
You have to store every attribute in a seperate column, to conform to 1 NF.