# Can I put an array inside a Mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

I have an array :

```
$arrayA = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Can I put an array like putting a constant number inside a query? like this:

```
SELECT id as 'ID',
       name as 'NAME',
       '1234' as 'Number'
FROM student
```

This above query will generate this:

```
ID    NAME    Number
1     Lily    1234
2     Sherry  1234
3     Bob     1234
4     Tom     1234
5     Lucy    1234
```

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT id as 'ID',
       name as 'NAME',
       $arrayA as 'Number'
FROM student
```

So if i have 5 students, when I do mysql_fetch_array it will automatically generate 1,2,3,4,5 under the Number column.

```
ID    NAME    Number
1     Lily    1
2     Sherry  2
3     Bob     3
4     Tom     4
5     Lucy    5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php to achieve this, such as

```
$students = array();
$arr = range(1,5);
$idx = 0;
while ( $row = $mysql_result->fetch_assoc())
{
  // return array(1,2,3,4,5)
  // $row['Number'] = $arr;

  // return matched
  // $row['Number'] = $arr[$idx];

  // this is what you can try
  $row['Number'] = ++$idx;
  $students[] = $row; 
}
```

NOTE: if you intend to use `oi`, and `li` tag for displaying,
you can opt this out

Comment: If I'm understanding peipei right, that should be `$row['Number'] = $arr[$i]`, with `$i` being a variable that starts at `0` and is incremented in each loop iteration. (That is, I think that peipei wants each student to receive one number from the array, rather than every student receiving the entire array.)

Comment: Thanks ajreal, I updated my post so make it more clear, I understand your answer, but can i also do it like that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Furthermore, you should not do this. It's violating first normal form. Each value should have its own column if there are a fixed number of values. If there are not a fixed number, you should have an intermediate table to handle the many-to-many relationship.

The whole idea behind relational databases is that each column stores one item of data per row. If you need to store more than one item of data, it should be in multiple columns or multiple rows.

See my answer to this question: [storing multiple data in one mysql column and retrieval of data individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121401/storing-multiple-data-in-one-mysql-column-and-retrieval-of-data-individually/8121459#8121459)

Comment: I didn't know that 1nf is saying that an array is not a "value". I still think that if You store different arrays per row, 1nf is still there... And if one "should not do this" then why You can store and work with arrays, array tables, matrixes, etc. in other DBMS than MySQL?

Comment: 1NF says that values with different meaning should be stored in separate columns or rows. Since the OP said "if i have 5 students, when I do mysql_fetch_array it will automatically generate 1,2,3,4,5", it's clear in this case that they are talking about different values for different students. This should be split out correctly.